# Timesheet formula to show percentages by user within a time frame

Tags: excel, time, pivot-table, percentage, sumifs

I have an Excel spreadsheet of time log data with about 10,000 rows with fields for Project, Date, User, and Hours that looks like this:

```
Project     Date        User    Hours
1A          7/8/2014    123     0.75
1A          7/9/2014    123     1
2A          7/10/2014   123     2.5
1B          7/11/2014   123     0.5
2A          7/11/2014   456     0.5
```

How can I write a formula that I can apply to all 10,000 rows of data that will give me the percentage of time spent on a project per user within a certain time frame? So for example, between 1/1/14-3/31/14 I want to know what percentage of User 123's time was spent on each project that they worked on during that time frame.

Comment: Excel isn't the best tool for this. The result you want--a unique list of all the users & time percentages--does not have the same dimensionality as the input data. Would be much better do convert the spreadsheet to a SQL database and then query it for the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try a combination of [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) and 
[SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5).

For a full scope:

```
=sumifs(D:D, C:C, C2, A:A, A2)/sumif(C:C, C2, D:D)
```

For a dated scope:

```
=sumifs(D:D, B:B, ">="&DATE(2014, 1, 1), B:B, "<"&DATE(2014, 4, 1), C:C, C2, A:A, A2)/sumifs(D:D, B:B, ">="&DATE(2014, 1, 1), B:B, "<"&DATE(2014, 4, 1), C:C, C2)
```

Format as a percentage.

Comment: @pnuts - Yes, I'll admit my response was a little lazy. Modified to show the OP's date criteria now.

Answer (score 2):

Pivot your data with `User` under `Project` for ROWS and Sum of `Hours` for VALUES. `Date` in FILTERS. For VALUES select Field Settings... and Show Values As % of Parent Row Total and filter to chose your selected `User` and `Date` or date range.